# Flex 4 Progress bar Show Minutes are left

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, progress-bar, flex4, flex4.5

I upload a file on server and the progress is showing through progress bar. When i upload the file in flex 4 how can i calculate the time that how many minutes are left when we upload the file on server.

Please if anyone has any idea please share.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not very sure this can be determined with consistency and accuracy . You can do one thing , once the upload starts get hold of the time and at each interval calculate the amount of file transferred `x` bytes and the corresponding time `t` seconds . Then the upload speed will be around `x/t` bytes/second . Let say the total size is `total` bytes , then the time remaining will be `(total-x)/(x/t)` .

If you want to use some ready made custom component look at [this](http://soegianto.com/blog/2008/07/multiple-file-upload-with-flex-and-php/).